# Python: Initiate a variable once in a program running every few minutes

Tags: python, initialization

I have a program running every minutes. I want that when I'm executing it for the first time I do something and after something else; like this :

```
def alarm_function (alarm):
    first_time=0
    if first_time==0:
        send_on_website(message)
        first_time+=1
        alarm=0
    else:
        send_on_website(a_different_message)
    if alarm==0:
        #do nothing
    if alarm==1:
        alarm+=1
        #do something
```

So basically after I executed once I want to erase the first line "first_time=0" because I don't want to initiate it again. Also, I want to make a counter on alarm variable which is initiate somewhere in the program. How can I do that ?

Comment: keep value in file and read/write it

Comment: Yes I had the feeling it was the only way but I prefered to asked ! Thanks

Comment: Please define "running every few minutes" / reword your post. From my understanding, both answers below my comment are incorrect and think that your program continuously runs.

Comment: you can use `pickle`, `json` or `yaml` to write/read easier.

Comment: @furas Why would you invoke such modules for storing 1 bit of information?

Comment: I already have a file where I initiate some values, it name is datalog.py and I'm doing this

    test1=datalog.test
I will try to do 

    datalog.test=test1

Comment: `datalog.test=test1` will not save data in file. you will have to use `open()`, `write()` to rewrite all file.

Comment: @Krazor because it is nice and easy. But you can suggest own solution.

Comment: Okay that is true. And no I won't, I was just wondering if yaml is actually as fast as plain writing to a file  :)

Comment: @Krazor maybe yaml is not so fast as plain writing but for small file you will not see difference. Maybe for big file you will see diference.

Comment: In fact, I use my file datalog to configure variables for an other programm. I never used  `pickle` and `json`, will it be more effective than `open()` and `write()` ? Because I don't want to overwrite my file everytime, just overwrite the concern variable.

Comment: And I got a question with `write()` , if my program have to modify one specific alarm, how can I do that. For my example, it will be alarm_W_A :
In datalog we have :
`alarm_W_A=1
alarm_UPS=1
alarm_N_W_A=1`
And I want to write `alarm_W_A=2` If I copy everything in the file, how can I do to change only this line ?

Comment: If you're actually storing properties/several variables, using yaml is the way to go seeing as it is tested and easy to use. You could of course use a database as well. I suggest taking a look at `sqlitedict` for fast productivity with Pythons default database sqlite.

Comment: I only need to handle maybe 15 variables. Is it necessary to use a library ? If I have to store a new value for an alarm it will be only occasional, like maybe once or twice a day. If it possible I don't want to add with append this new value but re-write it on my variable. Did you think I can do that with something like `writelines()` ?

Comment: Of course you *could*, the question is if it would be worth doing that. A great thing about coding is that one can reuse already build software, same way you would not proof 1+1 when calculating some science-level math. So just use PyYaml or Sqlite, there are plenty of good tutorials out there :)

Answer (score 0):

you would have to define a new function if you dont want the first_time any more. and for the counter you can put at the top of your program `import time` and where ever you want the counter to be you use `time.sleep(?) #change ? for a any number of seconds`